# Step to use a GPU NVIDIA AX4000 that is configured in Window 10 PRO in a ubuntu 20.04 VM on Hyper Visor?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, gpu, hyper-v, window

**UPDATED QUESTION**

My host Os is Window10 Pro which has an Nvidia AX4000 GPU.

I want to create the Ubuntu20.04 virtual machine by using an Hypervisor of type 1 (Hyper-V) and be able to use that GPU.

After many headaches, a solution that i found may be quite a ugly work around:

- Create a VM with Windows Server 2019 as guestOS. Then apply GPU partitioning among the two OS.
- Secondly, create in WindowServer19 VM another VM but this time with Ubuntu20.04 installed and do GPU passthrough.

Any other solutions ?

Comment: what do you mean recover the settings, a VM releases any host resources (except drive space when its not running)?  VirtualBox doesn't passthrough GPUs.  Hyper-V doesn't either, but supports Direct Device Assignment (DDA)...which is similar but not the exact same thing.

Comment: I mean make the GPU working in the Host OS as before to apply the GPU passthrough procedure or other similar techniques. 

Do you maybe know also which Manager support the GPUs passthrough in Window10 PRO ?

Comment: With workstation Hyper-V (I have it herer), Hyper-V provides the Video hardware emulation. You cannot use the GPU directly.  Same for all the the VM apps I use. So there are no settings to recover.  The settings are in the Host machine.

Comment: Thanks, Great!. I updated the question with your suggesting.

Comment: @John, Hyper-V allows for GPU partitioning, so while can't directly use the whole GPU, you can get access to the hardware, see "gpu-p"

Comment: I read hyper-V allows GPU partition only for Guest Os which are Windows-like and not Ubuntu. At the same time Hyper-V allows GPU passthrough from Window Server2016+ towards Ubuntu20.04.
By other hand, VMware solutions allow vGPU procedure but it is not a GPU passthrough process and as a consequence performances may be reduced.

Comment: At the moment I opted for VMware solutions, even though I got poor performance. I would prefer to work with free hypervisor softwares.